# Emacs - evil-mode causes flicker in eldoc-mode

Tags: emacs, elisp, evil-mode

Any movement commands cause the eldoc-message in the minibuffer to flicker.  Disabling evil-mode eliminates the flicker.

From the eldoc documentation, I found this relevant snippet.

```
;; This function goes on pre-command-hook for XEmacs or when using idle
;; timers in Emacs.  Motion commands clear the echo area for some reason,
;; which make eldoc messages flicker or disappear just before motion
;; begins.  This function reprints the last eldoc message immediately
;; before the next command executes, which does away with the flicker.
;; This doesn't seem to be required for Emacs 19.28 and earlier.
(defun eldoc-pre-command-refresh-echo-area ()
  (and eldoc-last-message
       (if (eldoc-display-message-no-interference-p)
           (eldoc-message eldoc-last-message)
         (setq eldoc-last-message nil))))
```

How do I prevent the flicker with evil-mode enabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, evil-mode is innocent.  The culprit is [key-chord.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/key-chord.el).

The display flickers when a key is pressed that was present in `key-chord-define`.  I had "jk" bound to `keyboard-quit`, so every time I pressed `j` or `k`, eldoc would flicker.

```
(key-chord-define-global "jk" 'keyboard-quit)
```

This isn't a bug in evil-mode. It's just more noticeable in evil-mode because of the single letter commands like `h` and `j`.

I patched key-chord at https://github.com/jschaf/key-chord to fix the flicker.  See [commit a2f6c61](https://github.com/jschaf/key-chord/commit/a2f6c61f55dfb571011f415b45b4f85bcd1af840) for the actual fix.